# unable to execute "delete" query in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

in a swing button I set a action that it execute delete query and execute another class.
here's my code:

```
JButton btnScanMyPc = new JButton("SCAN MY PC");
    btnScanMyPc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try{
                String q="DELETE FROM `search` WHERE 1=1 ";
                PreparedStatement st=connection.prepareStatement(q);
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
                ReadDir rd = new ReadDir();
                ReadDir.main(null);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}


        }
```

when i execute this query in database it works perfectly. but in java it shows some error like:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation Statement with executeQuery().
```

Comment: That error message could not be more clear, right?

Comment: yeah this error message is not clear.

Comment: kon was saying that the error message **is** clear

Comment: @RakibAlHasan The error message is extremely clear, if you would just read it. It clearly explains what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: sorry sir i did not understand what you said first.
but now its clear.
and sir i am learning so its not so much easy for me to understand .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) instead of `executeQuery()` for data manipulation like `Insert`,`Update` or `Delete`.

Comment: sir  i tried but its not working..
error:
type mismatch cannot convert from int to ResultSet.

Comment: Yes as this method does not return resultset.You will get the number of rows affected by your query as a result.So store result of executeUpdate in int variable.Please go to the executeUpdate link for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
 "DELETE FROM search WHERE 1=1 "

 st.executeUpdate(q);
```